# Publish Kotlin MPP metadata with Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: maven, kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a Kotlin MPP to share Json utilities between JVM and JS. All the code lies in the common source set and I have configured the necessary targets with their respective dependencies. Without further configuration I'm able to use the utilities from both JVM and JS but not from the common source set of another MPP, which has to do with the way Gradle handles metadata.

I already found the solution (taken from https://medium.com/xorum-io/crafting-and-publishing-kotlin-multiplatform-library-to-bintray-cbc00a4f770)

```
afterEvaluate {
    project.publishing.publications.all {
        groupId = group
        if (it.name.contains('metadata')) {
            artifactId = "$libraryName"
        } else {
            artifactId = "$libraryName-$name"
        }
    }
}
```

and I also got it to work with the Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing.publications.all {
        this as MavenPublication
        artifactId = project.name + "-$name".takeUnless { "metadata" in name }.orEmpty()
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't feel quite right yet.

1. There is no such code snippet in the official documentation.
2. The documentation advertises that a single dependency from the common source set should suffice to automatically resolve target specific dependencies: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#metadata-publishing. I had to add the dependency for each target, respectively, for it to work.
3. `this as MavenPublication` is necessary because `Publication` has no field `artifactId`.
4. I use `project.name` instead of `libraryName`.

Is this even remotely the right way to do things or am I missing some other option which would make the whole process trivial?

Right now I'm using Kotlin `1.3.72` and Gradle `5.2.1` with `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` in `settings.gradle.kts`. I also tried it with Gradle `6.5.1` (latest) but it behaves exactly the same.

For now I'm glad that it's working at all but I suspect there is a cleaner way to do this. I'd really appreciate if someone with a bit more Gradle expertise could clear things up for me or point me into the right direction.

Edit:

`gradle.build.kts` for completeness. Although there isn't much going on here.

```
group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.72"
    `maven-publish`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm()

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
            }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Throw away that "solution". Are you pushing to bintray or maven central/sonatype?

Comment: Show me a better one and I'm delighted to do so. It's a small personal project so I'm publishing to my own maven repository for now.

Comment: People generally publish to bintray or sonatype. I'm not sure what your own maven repo is, unless you mean local I guess.

Comment: To be clear, doing something special with metadata like that is wrong. You absolutely don't need to. I don't have a blog post explaining how to config your publishing, but I can point you to plenty of libraries we publish, both to public and local repos.

Comment: Also, post the rest of your config, what version of Gradle, Kotlin, etc. That part of your config will no longer exist as it's not necessary, but it would be useful to see the rest of your config.

Comment: That would be great! I just want the minimal setup to work. If it works with maven local it will also work with my repository, I think there's no relevant difference besides caching. (I tried it with both, my repository and maven local anyways. The solution shouldn't be dependent on how bintray, ... handle publishing). See edit for my `build.gradle.kts`.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't really a problem after all. The solution is to simply add `enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` to the consuming project too.

According to https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#metadata-publishing this shouldn't be necessary:

> In earlier Gradle versions starting from 5.3, the module metadata is
> used during dependency resolution, but publications don't include any
> module metadata by default. To enable module metadata publishing, add
> enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA") to the root project's
> settings.gradle file.

Weirdly it only works when both publishing project and consuming project have metadata enabled, even when both use the latest Gradle version.

Comment: Yeah, that: https://twitter.com/kpgalligan/status/1189895057404510208?s=20

Answer (score 0):

`enableFeaturePreview("GRADLE_METADATA")` is enabled by default in latest gradle.
According to [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/mpp-publish-lib.html) you need to substitute "kotlinMultiplatform" by "" an empty string.

I finally managed to accomplish publishing to bintray with `maven-publish` plugin only, without outdated bintray library.
Here is my full `maven.publish.gradle.kts`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.*
import org.gradle.api.publish.PublishingExtension

apply(plugin = "maven-publish")

val fis = FileInputStream("local.properties")
val properties = Properties().apply {
    load(fis)
}
val bintrayUser = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
val bintrayApiKey = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")
val bintrayPassword = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password")
val libraryVersion: String by project
val publishedGroupId: String by project
val artifact: String by project
val bintrayRepo: String by project
val libraryName: String by project
val bintrayName: String by project
val libraryDescription: String by project
val siteUrl: String by project
val gitUrl: String by project
val licenseName: String by project
val licenseUrl: String by project
val developerOrg: String by project
val developerName: String by project
val developerEmail: String by project
val developerId: String by project

project.group = publishedGroupId
project.version = libraryVersion

afterEvaluate {
    configure<PublishingExtension> {
        publications.all {
            val mavenPublication = this as? MavenPublication
            mavenPublication?.artifactId =
                "${project.name}${"-$name".takeUnless { "kotlinMultiplatform" in name }.orEmpty()}"
        }
    }
}

configure<PublishingExtension> {
    publications {
        withType<MavenPublication> {
            groupId = publishedGroupId
            artifactId = artifact
            version = libraryVersion

            pom {
                name.set(libraryName)
                description.set(libraryDescription)
                url.set(siteUrl)

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set(licenseName)
                        url.set(licenseUrl)
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id.set(developerId)
                        name.set(developerName)
                        email.set(developerEmail)
                    }
                }
                organization {
                    name.set(developerOrg)
                }
                scm {
                    connection.set(gitUrl)
                    developerConnection.set(gitUrl)
                    url.set(siteUrl)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven("https://api.bintray.com/maven/${developerOrg}/${bintrayRepo}/${artifact}/;publish=1") {
            credentials {
                username = bintrayUser
                password = bintrayApiKey
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin-multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
    sourceSets {
        jvm()
        js() {
            browser()
            nodejs()
        }
        linuxX64()
        linuxArm64()
        mingwX64()
        macosX64()
        iosArm64()
        iosX64()

        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
            }
        }

        val jsMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val jsTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
            }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
            }
        }

        val nativeMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
            }
        }

        val linuxX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val linuxArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val mingwX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val macosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val iosArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(nativeMain)
        }
    }
}

apply(from = "maven.publish.gradle.kts")
```

Please note, there are `bintray.user` and `bintray.apikey` properties in `local.properties` file.
Also `gradle.properties` contains rest listed properties above:

```
libraryVersion = 0.5.22
libraryName = MultiplatformCommon
libraryDescription = Kotlin multiplatform extensions
publishedGroupId = com.olekdia
artifact = multiplatform-common
bintrayRepo = olekdia
bintrayName = multiplatform-common
siteUrl = https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/multiplatform-common
gitUrl = https://gitlab.com/olekdia/common/libraries/multiplatform-common.git
.........
kotlin.mpp.enableGranularSourceSetsMetadata = true
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure = true
```

If you haven't created organisation in bintray you need to change in this url:

```
https://api.bintray.com/maven/${developerOrg}/${bintrayRepo}/${artifact}/;publish=1
```

`developerOrg` by `bintrayUser`, where the last one is your user name at bintray.com